Error in system(cmd, intern = intern, ignore.stdout = ignore.stdout, ignore.stderr = ignore.stderr)
I am running an R script that uses cifti and am getting this error:
Error in system(cmd, intern = intern, ignore.stdout = ignore.stdout, ignore.stderr = ignore.stderr) :
  error in running command
Calls: as.matrix ... read_cifti_convert -> info_cifti -> header_cifti -> run_wb_cmd -> system
Execution halted

It returns when doing this line of code in the script
bold_cifti = as.matrix(read_cifti(cifti_fname, 
                                  surfL_fname = "path to file",
                                  surfR_fname = "path to file") )

I am not able to find any particular reason as to why this is being returned. I am running this on windows subsystem Ububtu Jammy. I would really appreciate any help in understanding why this is happening

It is trying to run some external command, and that is failing.  You should find out what it is trying to run (by using debugonce(system) just before the call to read_cifti(), and printing command).  Then figure out why that command didn't work.
